# Getting "Cannot call Method of "sendKeys" of undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I working on building some tests via the JMeter Webdriver plugin and am having issues with entering text into a textbox. Here is my code:

```
var textField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('element_id'))
textField.click()
textField.sendKeys('JMeter Test')
```

I get undefined for the sendKey method but both the findElement and .click() commands work without error...I have tried using .clear() as well with no luck. I have used the sendKeys command multiple times prior without issue. The field is in a modal, if that is relevant. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: are you able to instead use `textField.value('JMeter Test')` ? If that works, then you can use that, or at least you have confirmed that Selenium has found the Element.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874491/jmeter-webdriver-sampler it may/may not help or apply just thought I would share.

Answer (score 1):

Okay..tried a bunch of complicated fixes but all I needed to do was add brackets...I thought you only needed to use brackets with variables but I guess not. So the code that worked was:

```
var textField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('element_id'))
textField.click()
textField.sendKeys(['JMeter Test'])
```

Thanks for your responses, Adam T.

Comment: Thanks @dstronge I'll keep that in mind for future with sendKeys questions with JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all options, but nothing worked.
I changed the script Language from java to groovy. Then it worked.

```
var uname=WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@id='username']"));
uname.click();
uname.sendKeys("sampleUserName");
```